# How to Iterate on table using js

Tags: javascript, python, html

Hi I am trying to iterate the table. So that I can view in the UI. By using my sql  select query to view the records in python.

```
Designation  Number  person
abc            2      ram
sdf            3      raj
bnd            4      sai
....          ...     ...
```

---

```
<div id="myDynamicTable">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td ><b>Designation<b></td>
            <td >role</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Number </b></td>
            <td >"""+two+"""<td/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>person</b></td>
            <td>"""+name+"""<td/>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
for (var i=0; i<role_title_count.length; i++){

    for (var j=0; j<5; j++){
        var td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cell " + i + "," + j));
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
}
</script>
```

I am using python to get mysql records and html/css to view UI . I am using the script in html page only.Can any one help me out with solution .

Comment: What is `role_title_count`? And what is the **specific** problem?

Comment: You will have to use 2 loops. First `#table tr`. Second `tr td`

Comment: You can also use datatables. Quick and easy to display your results in a table. Moreover it gives you the search, sort and pagination functionality as well. https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Comment: hi @Rax Weber role_title_count will give the count of table we have.

Comment: hi @Monasha thans for editing